# rake db:create is not working in Ubuntu

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu, activesupport

I am currently tring to run the `rake db:create` command on Ubuntu Xenial 16.04.01 but I am getting the error below.

> Your bundle is locked to activesupport (5.0.0.1), but that version
>   could not be found in any of the sources listed in your Gemfile. If
>   you haven't changed sources, that means the author of activesupport
>   (5.0.0.1) has removed it. You'll need to update your bundle to a
>   different version of activesupport (5.0.0.1) that hasn't been removed
>   in order to install.

I have tried running the command below to try to get the new version of active support but it is still not working..

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ruby-activesupport
```

Any help or advice would be much appreciated.

Comment: remove your `rm -rf Gemfile.lock` then do `bundle install`

Comment: The answer by @31piy worked and I have solved the problem, but thank you for the advice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sudo apt-get update` has nothing to do with ruby gems.

From the error, it seems like your `Gemfile.lock` has the version 5.0.0.1 of `ActiveSupport`, but it isn't declared in your `Gemfile`.

Can you try to add `gem activesupport` in your `Gemfile`, and then run `bundle install` from within the project folder? This should solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! 
Pretty sure it should work, but having another new problem instead in installing the mysql2 gem in my gemfile. Obviously this problem is off-topic so I would look for the answer to that somewhere else. Thanks!